# Layout manager problems while programming UI

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

There is a specific UI that I am trying to create for a Java program and I have been having trouble choosing the adequate Layout Managers. I would like my program to have a top panel with three elements (Two JTextFields and one JButton) and a lower JPanel that has another JPanel inside. The inner panel should always be a square, centered according to its container and adapt to the maximum height or width of its container. I have tried using a ComponentAdapter to achieve the effect of always staying a square, but the program does not seem to act the way I want it to, also the top Panel seems to get squeezed to the top

```
JPanel maincontainer = new JPanel();
    maincontainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(maincontainer, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel();
    jpanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    JTextField txt = new JTextField();
    txt.setFocusable(false);
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.setFocusable(false);
    JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();
    txt2.setFocusable(false);
    jpanel2.add(txt);
    jpanel2.add(btn);
    jpanel2.add(txt2);
    maincontainer.add(jpanel2);


    JPanel masterPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel centerPane = new JPanel();
    masterPane.add(centerPane);
    masterPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if(masterPane.getHeight()<masterPane.getWidth())
                centerPane.setSize(masterPane.getHeight(), masterPane.getHeight());
            else
                centerPane.setSize(masterPane.getWidth(), masterPane.getWidth());
        }

    });
    centerPane.setBackground(Color.blue);

    masterPane.add(centerPane);
    maincontainer.add(masterPane);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.getContentPane().add(maincontainer);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
```

[image: desired UI]
[image: obtained UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like my program to have a top panel with three elements (Two JTextFields and one JButton) and a lower JPanel that has another JPanel inside.

The easiest way to do this is to keep using the default layout manager of the frame which is a `BorderLayout`. You add the panel with the text fields and buttons to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. Then you add the panel that changes dynamically to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

> The inner panel should always be a square, centered according to its container and adapt to the maximum height or width of its container

The easiest way to center a component on a panel is to use a `GridBagLayout` on the panel. The default `GridBagConstraints` will cause the component to be displayed at it preferred size centered both vertically and horizontally. So you will need a wrapper panel using the GridBagLayout to contain your center panel.

You would then want to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your center panel to dynamically change as the size of the parent panel changes. This is a better approach than using a ComponentListener.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{

    SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JPanel top = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 3) );
        top.add( new JTextField(10) );
        top.add( new JButton("Button") );
        top.add( new JTextField(10) );
        add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel center = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize()
            {
                Dimension parent = getParent().getSize();

                if (parent.width < parent.height)
                    return new Dimension(parent.width, parent.width);
                else
                    return new Dimension(parent.height, parent.height);

            }
        };
        center.setBackground( Color.BLUE );

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        wrapper.add(center, new GridBagConstraints());

        add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }


static class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}

}
```